# Finite union of affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme and suppose that $X$ admits a finite open covering $(U_i)_{i\in I }$ of affine schemes, such that $X_i\cap X_j$ is an affine scheme, for all $i,j\in I$. In this case is it true that $X$ is an affine scheme?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not true. Any projective space $\Bbb P_k^n$ for a field $k$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for the helpfull remark :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another (horrible!) example: the union

$$ \mathbb{A}^2_R \setminus \{ (0,0) \} = \operatorname{Spec}(R[x, y, x^{-1}]) \cup \operatorname{Spec}(R[x, y, y^{-1}]) $$

is *not* an affine scheme (despite being a subscheme of an affine scheme!). The intersection of the two patches is

$$\operatorname{Spec}(R[x, y, x^{-1}]) \cap \operatorname{Spec}(R[x, y, y^{-1}])
= \operatorname{Spec}(R[x, y, x^{-1}, y^{-1}]) $$

Answer (score 0):

A mild generalization of Hurkyl's example is as follows. Consider any scheme $X$ which is:

1. quasi-compact
2. separated
3. quasi affine but not affine

A class of such schemes can be constructed as follows: For $k$ a field and $n,m>1$ take $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in k[x_1,\ldots, x_m]$ for which $ht(f_1,\ldots,f_n)>1$ and define the scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n}\mid_X)=D(f_1)\cup \ldots \cup D(f_n)$.

Then $X$, being finite union of quasi-compact spaces, is quasi-compact. Being an open subscheme of an affine scheme, $X$ is separated and quasi-affine. We only need to check that $X$ is not affine.

The regular functions on $X$ are precisely those $\frac{F}{G}\in k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ such that $V(G)\subset V(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$. But this cannot happen due to dimension reasons. Consequently, $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$. Thus, $X$ cannot be affine.