# Proposition $3.20$ of Algebraic Geometry and Aritmetic Curves- Qing Liu

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Can anyone explain me how the author can say that $Z$ is an affine scheme?

[image]

I thinked in a first moment that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203742/finite-union-of-affine-schemes) was the key point, but it doesn't work.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Could you tell us what condition $(3.2)$ is the author is referring to?

Comment: Also, what is your definition of closed immersion?

Comment: I call scheme a locally ringed space which admits an open covering of affine schemes and closed immersion an injective closed map between top. spaces with the proprerty that the maps induced on the stalks are surjective.

Comment: I think that Liu for condition $(3.2)$ means the following: $X$ admits a covering by a finite number of affine open subsets $(U_i)_i$ such that $U_i\cap U_j$ also admits a finite covering by affine open subsets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof isn't actually finished yet. It proceeds by using the already established correspondence between sheafs of ideals and closed immersions [Prop 2.24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wQXw.png).

By taking global sections of the exact sequence of sheaves
$$ 0 \to ker f^\# \to \mathcal{O}_X \to f^*\mathcal{O}_Z  \to 0 $$
we get an exact sequence of A-modules
$$ 0 \to J \to A \to \mathcal{O}_Z(Z)$$
where $ J = ker f^\#(X) $. Let $ g : Spec \,A/J \to Spec \, A $.
We want to show that $ Z $ is isomorphic to $ Spec \,A/J $.
Using the proposition it suffices to show that $ ker f^\# = ker g ^\# $.
We can do this by checking the equallity on all principal open subsets.
So let $ g  \in A $ and $ h = f^\#(g)$. Then $ f^{-1}(D(g)) = Z_h $. Tensoring the exact sequence of A-modules above with $A_g$ we get
$$ 0 \to J \otimes A_g \to A_g \to \mathcal{O}_Z(Z)_h$$
Here $A_g = \mathcal{O}_X(D(g)) $ and $ \mathcal{O}_Z(Z)_h = \mathcal{O}(Z_h) $. The later is clearly true Z is affine. But it truns out that i suffices for Z to have condition (3.2). Therefore we have the exact sequence
$$ 0 \to J \otimes A_g \to \mathcal{O}_X(D(g)) \to f^*\mathcal{O}_Z(D(g)) $$
This shows $ ker f ^\# (D(g)) =  J \otimes A_g $. By tensoring $ 0 \to J \to A \to A/J \to 0$ with $A_g$ it is easily seen that $ ker g^\# (D(g)) =  J \otimes A_g $ too.

It's also possible to prove that Z is affine first, without using the sheaf of ideals/closed immersion correspondence. Hartshorne gives some hints on how to do that(see Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry Chapter 2 Ex. 3.11.b).